# Which browsers support SNI?

Tags: https, ip-address, security-certificate

Because of the way web servers and SSL work, previously a dedicated IP address was required for running an SSL certificate on a domain.

But with a new technique (SNI, abbreviation for Server Name Indication) this is no longer a requirement. So which browsers **do** and do **not** support SNI?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**It should be noted that the following list has not been updated since November 2014.**

The following browsers **do** support SNI:

- Internet Explorer 7 or newer, on Windows Vista or newer.
- Mozilla Firefox 2.0 or later
- Opera 8.0 or newer (TLS 1.1 protocol needs to be enabled)
- Opera Mobile with at least version 10.1 bèta on Android
- Google Chrome (Vista or newer. XP on Chrome 6 or newer)
- OS X 10.5.7 or newer on Chrome 5.0.342.1 or newer
- Safari 2.1 or later (Mac OS X 10.5.6 or newer and Windows Vista or newer)
- Konqueror/KDE 4.7 or newer
- MobileSafari in Apple iOS 4.0 or newer
- Android default browser on Honeycomb or newer
- Windows Phone 7
- MicroB on Maemo

The following browsers do **not** support SNI:

- Internet Explorer, all versions, Windows XP
- Safari, Windows XP
- BlackBerry Browser
- Windows Mobile 6.5 and lower
- Android 2.x default browser

The following HTTP (web) servers **do** support SNI:

- Apache 2.2.12 or newer with mod_ssl
- F5 Networks Local Traffic Manager with version 11.1 or newer
- LiteSpeed 4.1 or newer
- Pound 2.6 or newer
- Apache Tomcat or Java 7 or newer
- Microsoft Internet Information Server IIS 8
- PageKite tunneling reverse proxy

The following HTTP (web) servers do **not** support SNI:

- IBM HTTP Server

**Edit**: Apparently there's a more complete list at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication#Support) :) (thanks @Tom Brossman)

Comment: +1 for the effort but readers would do well to also read the [SNI Support page over on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication#Support) which is more complete.

Comment: Additional note: Although not a browser per-say, Bingbot and Yahoobot agents/browsers technically don't support SNI nor FS. They still index https mode though.